# column listing misaligned after pane resize in iterm2

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

So, I use iterm2 (on mac os 11), with multiple panes in one window (e.g. horizontal and vertical splits). Sometimes after resizing either the whole iterm2 window, or just one of the panes within the window, the pane doesn't notice that it's been resized and then all the subsequent file listings are no longer neatly stacked in columns, like so:

[image: screenshot of unstacked columns]

I cannot figure out how to "refresh" this window so it notices the size change. I've attempted to google around for answers, but I'm not finding anyone else mention a similar problem -- mostly I'm finding stuff about resizing/restoring windows after connecting or disconnecting an external monitor. I've tried various versions of reset/clear/refresh, e.g. `cmd+r` ("reset"), `ctrl+l`, `clear`, as well as various iterm2 menu options, like "Window > Resize split pane" and "Window > Arrange split panes evenly", and none of them are resetting whatever it is that is confused.